# To find the adjoint of $Τ_P$, where $Τ_P$ is the linear operator on $V$ defined by $Τ_P (A) = Ρ^{-1}ΑΡ$.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, inner-products, adjoint-operators

Let $V$ be the space of $n \times n$ matrices over the complex numbers, with the 
inner product $(A,B) = tr (AB^*)$. Let $Ρ$ be a fixed invertible matrix in $V$, and let $Τ_P$ be the linear operator on $V$ defined by $Τ_P (A) = Ρ^{-1}ΑΡ$. Find the adjoint of $Τ_P$.

If adjoint of $Τ_P$ exists then $(T_PA,B) = (A,T_P^*B)$ where $T_P^*$ is the adjoint.

Answer (score 0):

By definition of the inner product on $V$, we have
$$
\begin{align}
tr(T_p(A) B^*)&=tr(P^{-1}AP B^*) \\
&=tr(APB^* P^{-1}) \ \ \textrm{ (since $tr(AB)=tr(BA)$ for any $A,B$ in $V$) } 
\end{align}
$$

Thus, the adjoint operator $T_P^*$ must satisfy
$$
(T_P^*(B))^* = P B^* P^{-1}. 
$$
Then we have
$$
T_P^*(B) = (P^{-1})^* B P^*. 
$$